# How do you sort a list of tuples without using sort() or lambda() function?

Tags: python, sorting

I have to sort a list of tuples without using any built-in function (like sort() or lambda()).

I know how to sort a normal list like so:

```
a=[2,1,3]  
   for i in range(0, len(a)):  
       for j in range(i+1,len(a)):  
           if (a[i]>a[j]):
               a[i],a[j]=a[j],a[i]
return a
```

My output is: [1,2,3]

However, when it comes to sorting a list of tuples like `(("b", 32), ("c", 1), ("a", 23))` and that I have to reorder it in order of the second element without using sort() or lambda() or any in-built function, I don't know how to do it. Can someone help me please?:)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much difference. you can use the same code with minor changes:
`

```
a=[2,1,3]  
    for i in range(0, len(a)):  
        for j in range(i+1,len(a)):  
            if (a[i][1]>a[j][1]):
                a[i],a[j]=a[j],a[i]
 return a
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is the same, just compare each second item of each element

```
if a[i][1] > a[j][1]:
```

Also `(("b", 32), ("c", 1), ("a", 23))` is a tuple, so it's immutable, use a list as outer container

```
def sort_tuples():
    a = [("b", 32), ("c", 1), ("a", 23)]
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(a)):
            if a[i][1] > a[j][1]:
                a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]

    return a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the easiest sorting algorithm that is bubble sort.
In case of tuples in tuple it will sort in order of first element of tuple. So `((32, "b"), (1, "c"), (23,"a"))`  Now if you sort it it will sort it in the order of 1st element of tuple.